# Texture export to dae setting or procedural issues

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

Hello my fellow Blender Artists and Enthusiasts,

Testing Models and textures for personal use downloaded off the internet in preparation for a more serious project.

However, I just cant seem to make it work.

My my best guess, or hypothesis for this problem (or problems) is that my procedure to attach a UV texture map to my mesh and export as a dae.file is somehow incorrect or somehow missing a step.

I have 2 meshes with 2 separate texture maps.

I have tried to assign each map to each mesh separately as well as make sure they were uv unwrapped and attached.

My models (and also my simple animations) export to other display engines such as Aurasma or Sketchfab fine, except they have no textures or colors.

In Aurasma using the dae.export file format to add to a tar and upload, what I get is I see a purple wire mesh only.

In Sketchfab .blend file export (or in-bedded add on), I see a nice model ( white) however, no UV texture map or color.

I can render the test scenes in Blender as a PNG or Movie file, and the colors etc. come out fine.

I export the models and no.

As far as I can tell, (and I have walked through several tutorials to check for proper procedural sequence) I am missing something (probably obvious) to someone more familiar with the settings.

I will attach screen shots and a link to the blend file if helpful at the bottom to try and make it more clear.

I am currently Using Windows 7 Blender version 2.77a.

I am trying to keep it simple and using only blender render.

Some of the things I have tried so far.

Checked settings for Aurasma upload

https://aurasma.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205627909-3D-Model-Troubleshooting

and also

https://aurasma.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/206382776-3D-Overlay-Specifications-formerly-3D-Guidelines-

I did this (to the best of my knowledge)

1. Triangulate Faces
2. Before exporting your model or animation you must triangulate the faces.  To do this, get into Edit Mode (Next to view on bottom – select 3D mode, then select “edit mode” next to mesh. In edit mode, select all faces you need to triangulate, and then press CTR-T.

Export your work as collada (.dae) using the default settings.
Bundle your file with a thumbnail and a sound file....as a TAR

A .tar file should contain:

```
The exported/scene model using OpenCollada (.dae file)
All textures referenced in the scene file (.png format)
.png thumbnail (256×256 pixels), named thumbnail.png
```

This didn't work, so then I looked over many tutorials and tried these below.

https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?229354-Textures-are-not-exporting-with-collada

and

http://support.ponoko.com/hc/en-us/articles/220291008-How-to-export-a-STL-design-file-using-Blender-2-6-

and

still making my way through this one....

I also tried editing and looking through my out liner for anomalies following below link and a few other tutorials to see if maybe something wasn't attached right somehow.

http://blender-manual-i18n.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/editors/outliner.html

https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?344926-dae-files-unable-to-import-textures

My scene and export settings look like this

[image: Materials]

[image: Textures]

[image: export .dae settings]

[image: more .dae export settings attempt]

Download original blend file here

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx2FdbWLpg_oY0phaERWMGg5dGM/view?usp=sharing

Any suggestions are welcome.

[image: Texture assignments and settings]

Comment: Animationprofessor, welcome to our site. You might want to take the [tour](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour), and consult the [help pages](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help). However, it is not clear to me what you are asking, on the one hand, and I am not convinced it is a blender issue, on the other. I am, therefore flagging this question.

Comment: Simply would like to get some advice on export settings for my blender 3d model so that it displays properly in Aurasma. The above steps are what I have tried so far with the final display not working correctly due to the output settings in Blender not being correctly outputted.

Comment: If you are a member of the Aurasma Studio community, there may well be someone there who can answer your questions about importing. If you have specific questions on how to get your blender model ready, in my view, those questions would be within the scope of this site. But as I read your question, you seem to have made the model the way you want it, and the issues are more on the import side in Aurasma, than in the export side of Blender.

Comment: Hello brasshat,  I see your point. As I think this through you have many good points.  I have already contacted the Aurasma Studio Community and am waiting to hear back, however while waiting it occurred to me that there are many ways to export Blender 3D Models.  and I was hoping that mabey there was a quick fix or that this might be a common issue.

Comment: I do apologize for the choppy and disorganized original post, I wasn't sure how to simplify my question and explanation and I had tried to post pictures of my screenshots but they did not come through.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you resolved this in the end.   I am having the same problem with the png texture files.  After trying lots of different things, I looked inside the dae file from the zenka site and noticed that it was not made using blender but with 3D Studio Max - so no wonder the instructions didn't work.

I also found this post http://rowanpeter.com/amidoinitrite/a-simple-cube-blender-2-62-and-aurasma-studio/  His dae file is made using blender but again the png texture files do not seem to be recognised by aurasma (or don't anymore, he has provided video evidence that it worked at some point.)

Sorry this isn't really an answer, but I thought knowing that the zenka file was not made with blender might help you.

If you did find a solution I would be grateful if you could share it with me.  I'll let you know if I have any luck myself!